# How to draw a (topographical) map using mobile phone sensors (GPS excluded)?

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, mobile, maps

This is more of a theoretical question than the actual specific one.

I'm thinking about creating an app that would draw a 2D map of it's surroundings inside some sort of building/cave/etc depending only on it's sensors except of GPS (and Wi-Fi, too).

The only way to achieve this, at least I can think of at the moment, is trying to use some sort of microphone echolocation. Basically, trying to simulate sonar system. The problem is, there's very little literature and research about it.

So, what are the ways to draw a topographical map using mobile phone (iOS, Android preferably) sensors? Are there any libraries for that out there?

Comment: is this really possible? have you seen some apps that do this? But this is interesting.

Comment: Well, that's actually what I'm trying to find out.. :)

Comment: There is an app called acoustic ruler which does measurements using sound waves so in theory this could be done. You would need to combine this with code to track the iphones orientation using the gyroscope.

Comment: @IgnasK any progress? Have you found an answer?

Comment: Still doing a research on the subject. The closest/simplest thing, at least for the moment, seems to try attaching some kind of external ultrasonic sensor via USB because native mobile phone sensors are still not powerful/applicable enough for this kind of project.

Comment: @IgnasK any news on the subject?

Comment: The surroundings IDK but it might be possible to have a 3D "tunnel" of the hight where you walked. The motion sensors should detect when you change elevation in Gs

Answer (score 0):

[This thesis](http://hkr.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:475619/FULLTEXT02.pdf) is about a research conducted to identify indoor positioning using sensors available in an Android device. Hope this will give you some support to your work.